# Winform Application run on windwos 10 but sending error on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks

I have developed a winform application targeting The 4.5 .Net framework , I packed it using advanced installer and then I installed it on several computers run windows 10 , the application is working fine , but when some of my client installed it on windows 7 computer ,when he click to open it an error pop up :
[The error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVHjD.png)

I know that .Net framework is the one who causing the problem but I want a solution that prevent my intervention on the clients computers .

And here is the details of the error :

```
CLR20r3

  Signature du problème 01: MM Restauration.exe

  Signature du problème 02: 1.0.0.0

  Signature du problème 03: 5e20f0d8

  Signature du problème 04: System.Drawing

  Signature du problème 05: 4.7.2558.0

  Signature du problème 06: 59d41483

  Signature du problème 07: 8ca

  Signature du problème 08: 27

  Signature du problème 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

  Version du système:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   1036

  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  3b3c

  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  3b3cffb8c795063b1fa88be1915a2504

  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  9fe7

  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  9fe705241c4e5c4cc4e9d65dd39fd1f8

Lire notre déclaration de confidentialité en ligne :
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x040c

Si la déclaration de confidentialité en ligne n’est pas disponible, lisez la version hors connexion :
  C:\Windows\system32\fr-FR\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: It clearly looks like the a `File Not Found` scenario. Maybe your app is looking for some file that doesn't exist in the Windows 7 environment. Maybe an image file as the error roots from `System.Drawing` ?

Comment: Indeed the System.Drawing Library is the one which rises the Io exception , but how can I find the issue with that library

Comment: Where do you get this exception? At start up? Maybe if you paste your app's constructor and/or Load event (if any) to understand what your app is trying to read/load from the system.

Comment: Yes at start up , but the System.drawing ,is not used at start up , in fact it's only used for the printing functionality

Comment: Can't tell mate without seeing the code. Could be security/privilege issue, could be just as Mathews mentioned. Could be something else. For now, run your app as Administrator in Window 7 to check the security issue.